# elliptc type function

Tags: calculus

looking for some series and using Mellin transform it is possible to get
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } -\frac{2 k^3 e^{\pi  k (-x)}}{e^{\pi  k (-x)}+1}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{\cosh \left(\frac{6 \pi  n}{x}\right) \text{csch}^4\left(\frac{2 \pi  n}{x}\right)}{2 x^4}+\frac{23 \coth \left(\frac{2 \pi  n}{x}\right) \text{csch}^3\left(\frac{2 \pi  n}{x}\right)}{2 x^4}\right)-\frac{7}{60 x^4}-\frac{1}{120}$$
 it may connect with the elliptic function?

Comment: If I may ask : how or where did you  find this expression ?

Comment: hi Claude use mellin transfrom you get for the function of the left $$2^{1-s} \left(2^s-2\right) \pi ^{-s} \zeta (s) \Gamma (s)$$ and use residue Cauchy you get for examples $$ \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } -\frac{2 k e^{\pi  k (-x)}}{e^{\pi  k (-x)}+1}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{2 \text{csch}^2\left(\frac{2 \pi  n}{x}\right)}{x^2}-\frac{\text{csch}^2\left(\frac{\pi  n}{x}\right)}{x^2}\right)-\frac{1}{6 x^2}+\frac{1}{12}$$ but i wish to connect all of this with elliptic agm theory

Comment: I am not familiar at all with Mellin  transforms but I am always impressed by the beauty of the expressions. I use to have a look to each of your questions. Thanks.

Comment: thanks claude for your interest

Comment: Mi gusto y mi placer, hombre !